# What does it mean when curly brackets just wrap the code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I checked the source code of Vue.js, I saw that there are lines of code between two curly brackets and there is no any definition before this construction (like `function`, `()=>` or another thing). I paste it in the console and it runs. But how can I use it, if I dont assign it to a variable?

What is this? Why should we use this way when we write code?

```
....
 var formatComponentName = (null); 

    {
      var hasConsole = typeof console !== 'undefined';
      var classifyRE = /(?:^|[-_])(\w)/g;
      var classify = function (str) { return str
        .replace(classifyRE, function (c) { return c.toUpperCase(); })
        .replace(/[-_]/g, ''); };

      warn = function (msg, vm) {
        var trace = vm ? generateComponentTrace(vm) : '';

        if (config.warnHandler) {
          config.warnHandler.call(null, msg, vm, trace);
        } else if (hasConsole && (!config.silent)) {
          console.error(("[Vue warn]: " + msg + trace));
        }
      };

      tip = function (msg, vm) {
        if (hasConsole && (!config.silent)) {
          console.warn("[Vue tip]: " + msg + (
            vm ? generateComponentTrace(vm) : ''
          ));
        }
      };
    }
    ...
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: @Marty thank you. It is clear for me now.

Answer (score 1):

What you're illustrating is called a block. The code sample you provided is a fairly uncommon approach to grouping a set of instructions for stylistic purposes, as a block without an `if`, `while`, `do...while`, `for`, or `with` doesn't change the way the code executes.

To demonstrate,

```
document.body.innerHTML = "Testing...";

{
  document.body.innerHTML += "1";
  document.body.innerHTML += "2";
  document.body.innerHTML += "3";
}

document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>...and there you have it!"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5crb1ezf/

is identical in practice to:

```
document.body.innerHTML = "Testing...";
document.body.innerHTML += "1";
document.body.innerHTML += "2";
document.body.innerHTML += "3";
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>...and there you have it!"
```

Both examples will output the same text to the browser:

> Testing...123
>   ...and there you have it!

---

On the other hand, if you are using a block in conjunction with a control structure, such as `if`, `while`, `do...while`, `for`, and `with`, it will change the way the code executes.

```
if (condition) {
  // conditional statement here
}
```

As marty above pointed out, the reference for blocks can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block